# Why am I getting inconsistent results with Read function on a Stream connected to network?

Tags: c#, networking, stream

I am using a simple function:-

```
while((br.Read(downbuffer, 0, downbuffer.Length)>0)
{
    //Write the data in downbuffer to a file.
}
```

While its working well for a file(tested multiple times on a zip file download- http://citylan.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cric-scoreslive/v8.5-Live%20Cricket%20Scores%20Desktop%20App.zip), its not working when the link refers to a HTML file(tested on http://www.mediafire.com/?rc3kj22p1tb4vi9). With the later link, it only downloads and write only about 1 KB of data, while the page is of about 60 KB.
If it has something to do with not being flushed or anything, wondering how is it working with the files download? Relative code is this:-(Running in a separate thread)-

```
wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
wres = wreq.GetResponse();
fs = new FileStream(totalpath, FileMode.Create);
bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
br = new BinaryReader(wres.GetResponseStream());
while((onecount=br.Read(downbuffer, 0, downbuffer.Length)>0)
{
    bw.Write(downbuffer, 0, onecount);
    totalcount += onecount;
}
```

totalpath leads to a file,nothing special.
downbuffer size is 20 KB, my internet speed is about 60 kBps(512kbps).

Comment: If you're simply copying one stream to another, why the BinaryWriter and Reader?

Comment: There are other things on my mind, and I need to begin this way.
Its a bit difficult to explain right now but I just know this is to be done for now.

Comment: BinaryReader: Reads primitive data types as binary values in a specific encoding. That's not what you want is it? The Read and Write methods are available on the underlying stream. Wrapping with BinaryReader/Writer is pointless. If you really want to carry on with this nonsense, try `bw.Flush` after your loop.

Comment: I've tried with bw.Flush() too, neither did the HTML page downloaded completely with it, and neither did the file in first link had any problems with bw.Flush inside the while loop(Of course its present outside the loop).

Comment: Secondly I need a Stream which can read all types of data, so I just thought binaryReader was a good choice. Its kinda simple download manager code for me.

Comment: You only use `Write(byte[], int, int)`, that method is also available for the bare stream. The BinaryWriter serves no purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You could solve the whole problem by avoiding it:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(uri, totalpath);
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to do it using BinaryReader, is there a way?
Especially I want to dig a little why its not working with HTML files when working good with other files? Its downloading a bit of data I can see by opening file, sometimes its 977 bytes,sometimes 987 bytes and likewise. Any ideas?